# Riesz spaces, continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let (X,d,E) be a vector metric space. I know the definition of continuous function from X to X. But I am unable to find the definition of continuous function from X×X to X. Can some help me with definition.thanks in advance. Also is it true in riesz spaces that whenever

1. a+b <= c implies a<=c and b<=c.

Comment: Here E is Riesz space

Answer (score 1):

The product space usually is equipped with the weakest topology such that the projection maps are continuous, i.e. preimage of open sets are open.
Since you have a metric space, this topology is equivalent to the metric topology coming from the product metric given by
the sum of the two metrics. With this metric, you can use the same epsilon delta definition that you normally use.